# Error Handling in Parsing JSON by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, error-handling

ok i have this following code that parses JSON from an ajax response using $.parseJSON of jquery

```
try{
   var indata = $.parseJSON(rsp);
}catch(err){
   alert("an error occured");
}
```

Now as I want to cover any possible errors gracefully I tried to do some error handling which is usually `try and catch` now this code doesn't work. I intentionally do some malformed JSON and pass it to the `$.parseJSON` but it doesn't really work. Now my question is how I can handle this error gracefully

Comment: That [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/TCEYy/1/) (I've tried it in Chrome). What actually happens?

Comment: it doesn't really work. my firebug still catches the error. and if I turned off the firebug it skips the catch

Comment: @JamesAllardice in my case it doesn't really work.. of course its not really my real code but its the closest code in my part

Comment: Try being more specific than just "doesn't really work". "Doesn't really work" doesn't really mean anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend handling errors in jquery ajax error callback. If you specify the `dataType` as json, you should end up in the `error` callback instead of `success` if the json string is not correctly formatted

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine it should be work, if not try 'jQuery' in place of '$'. e.g

```
try{
  var indata = jQuery.parseJSON(rsp);
}catch(err){
  alert("an error occured");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

> Prior to jQuery 1.9, $.parseJSON returned null instead of throwing an error if it was passed an empty string, null, or undefined, even though those are not valid JSON.

Are you using a jQuery version older than 1.9?